# JavaScript булевые значения

Tags: javascript

решил пройти булевые значения по JS, скачал книжку и наткнулся на пример:
[image: Пример из источника]
Прошу объясните, как в этом примере повлияли булевые значения, если можно было просто добавить определенные классы?
Желательно чтобы объяснение было проще, можно и много)

Спасибо.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/

Comment: не особо ищите здесь логику, просто разберитесь что в коде происходит и почему в результате видите то, что видите

Answer (score 0):

Тип данных boolean используется очень часто, когда нужно отразить 2 состояния. Они помогают динамично менять true на false и наоборот. Зачем заморачиваться с классами если проще использовать boolean.
В дальнейшем можно будет написать различные условия и изменять быстро элементы.